Kivy backend implementation
I am a hobbyist programmer. I have learnt python as my first programming language. I want to learn android mobile app development using python. And I am thinking to use Kivy for it. And now I got to know that kivy is only used for frontend.
The problem is that how will I implement backend in it like implementing API. I got to know that flask can be used for it but I didn't got any proper guide (And I don't even want to use flask(can use django BTW). I have understanding of Web development (HTML and CSS) so I can use web development python technologies. And also tell if there's any other way. And at last I would also like that I get a library which will be likely specified for these type of backend tasks.
I searched for it on browser but I didn't find anything perfectly helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
